# Bibliography appears as part of the last appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, appendices

I am writing my thesis and found that the bibliography appears as part of the last appendix. I am using `natbib` and A&A style Here you are the code I am using. I include the whole code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,english]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{epsfig}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{ctable}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{ctable}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{fix-cm} 

\usepackage{setspace} 

\usepackage{morefloats}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{pageno}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{psfrag,color}

\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\small} 

\renewcommand{\captionlabelfont}{\sffamily\bf}

\usepackage{subfig}

\setlength{\textwidth}{17cm}

\setlength{\textheight}{25cm}

\setlength{\headwidth}{17cm}

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-1.0cm}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.0cm}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1.0cm}

\setlength{\voffset}{-1.65cm}

\setlength{\hoffset}{0cm}

\onehalfspacing

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}

\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}

\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage} 

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\textbf{\thechapter. #1}}{}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textbf{\thesection. #1}}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}

\setlength{\headheight}{2\headheight}

\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.00}

\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.0}

\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.0}

\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.0}

\setcounter{totalnumber}{6} 

\newcommand{\Rsolar}{\mbox{$\rm R_{\odot}\:$}}

\newcommand{\Rsol}{\mbox{$\rm R_{\odot}$}}

\newcommand{\VR}{$V\hskip-0.0275cmR$}

\newcommand{\Rsolit}{$\rm \textit{R}_{\odot}\:$}

\newcommand{\Msol}{\mbox{\,$\rm M_{\odot}$}}

\newcommand{\Nestel}{\mbox{\,$\rm N_{\star}\:$}}        

\newcommand{\Testel}{\mbox{\,$\rm T_{\star}\:$}}        

\newcommand{\Restel}{\mbox{\,$\rm r_{\star}\:$}}        

\newcommand{\Bestel}{\mbox{\,$\rm B_{r_{\star}}\:$}}    

\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{eqnarray}}

\newcommand{\ea}{\end{eqnarray}}

\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}

\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\pagenumbering{roman}

\fancyhead[RE]{My thesis.}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\pagenumbering{arabic}  

     \chapter{Chapter1}\label{Chapter1}

ble ble ble \citep{Andrews}


\appendix

    \chapter{Appendix1}\label{Appendix1}

bla bla bla


  {

  \backmatter

   \cleardoublepage 

  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

  \newpage

   \bibliographystyle{aa}

   \bibliography{aamnem99,tesi-bib}

 \begin{description}

 \bibitem[Andrews(2222)]{Andrews} Andrews, H.C. (Prentice-Hall, Inc., EnglewoodCliffs, New York).

 \end{description}

  }


\end{document}
```

If I substitute the last part between brackets by...

```
        {
    \cleardoublepage

    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth {#1}{#1}}

    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

    \lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bf\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{}}

    \rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bf {\bf Bibliography}}]{\fancyplain{}{\bf\thepage}}

    \chead{}

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

    \bibliographystyle{aa}

    \bibliography{aamnem99,aabib}



\begin{description}

 \bibitem[Andrews(2222)]{Andrews} Andrews, H.C. (Prentice-Hall, Inc., Englewood Cliffs, New York).

 \end{description}

        }
```

...then I cat separate the bibliography from the appendix but I don't get a page with the title "bibliography".

Any help on this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: depending on what document class you're using, since you appear to be using bibtex, you shouldn't have to say `\input{Bibliography}`.  if you have run (the program) bibtex on the `<main file>` (the items to be included will be identified from the `<main file>.aux` file), the `\bibliography{...}` command will include this material (in the `.bbl` file) automatically.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. And please stop using `\usepackage{everythingbutthekitchensink}`.

Comment: Nothing in the code you post prevents the bibliography heading appearing, presuming you are using bibtex in the standard way.  You should provide a complete self-contained document that exhibits the problem, and remove as much irrelevant material as possible.

Comment: Running the example above, i get an error about a not found bib-file, leading to no printed bibliography. The description environment indeed, does belong to the appendix. Explains the second observation as well. Since this is mainly a user mixup, and can be found in every single basic tutorial, this won't help many people in the future, but keeps this utter wrong stuff above on the internet. This isn't even a *don't do this* thing in my POV. I vote to close and recommend deletion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is resolvable by correct inputting, so basically a typo. Also, please have a look at the comment above.